# CSV File upload - Containing more than million records

Tags: spring-boot, csv, apache-kafka

We have an use case , like in our Spring boot application, we have an File upload where we need to upload csv file which could have more than a million records.
For now we could able to load 0.3 millions of records but unable to load the full data.
We are using Apache Kafka on this part where we push the uploaded csv file data as messages to Kafka topic and from Kafka our spring boot Kafka Consumer will listen for any data available in the topic.

Could you provide us any better suggestion if any. Thanks

Comment: Why are you not able to load full data?

Comment: Do you have any errors? Please share more information of your problem.